# SQL querying for a record and then searching in the previous records for existence

Tags: php, sql, ajax

I have a task in which i have to search for the details of IDs in a csv file. For this I have used `'in'` clause by which i can process only 1000 ids at a time. But the problem is after getting the records for example email associated with the id then I have to search the database if the same email has made any entry within a given time period (one year) and declare the ID is old and not new otherwise new. The database is very large.

I have used the `'in'` clause again for this. I have around 1,00,000 ids to process. Every 1000 ids requires 2 queries one for getting email and second for searching them. The entire process is taking me more than 25 minutes. I am trying to find better ways for achieving the same result.

Comment: One idea would be to import the CSV to a temp table and do the whole diff operation with a stored procedure/function.

Comment: can you tell me how to import the CSV file into a temp table

Comment: That would depend greatly on what RDBMS you're using. MySQL?

Comment: I am using Oracle SQL.